# Safari does not fire onmousedown fast

Tags: jquery, html, safari

I just find this issue weird. I have this jquery method:

```
$(".UserLink").mousedown(function(event){
  if(event.which == 3)  {
    $(".UserLink").attr("href", "www.google.com");
  }
});
```

I also have this html code:

```
<a class="UserLink" href="#">
  <div>My Links</div>
</a>
```

What happens is that the `mousedown` event does not fire as fast in Safari as compared to Firefox, Chrome and IE. Therefore, the `UserLink` href did not change in Safari as compared to IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Is there any explanation as to why this happens?

Comment: oops!!! let me change that. hehehe...

Comment: The event doesn't fire because event.which == 3is never true. In Safari as well as in Chrome event.which is 1.

Chrome Console:
which: 1

Safari Console:
which: 1

Comment: This code is to capture the right-click event. Which means that if the user does a right-click, it will change the `href` value. Then when the user clicks the "Open in new tab", it will redirect it to the value in `href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(".UserLink").mousedown(function(event){
          if(event.which == 3)  {
            $(".UserLink").attr("href", "www.google.com");
          }
        });
    });
```

Instead of `onmousedown` cheange it to `mousedown` event.
Here `event.which` is reading the value as 1, so it will jump out of the if condition.

Comment: it is already inside the `document.ready()`. but it still does not fire.

Comment: Yup. even so. When the user does a right-click for this link in safari, it does not fire the setting of the href to the link. This one works in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: Instead of `$(".UserLink").attr("href", "www.google.com");` try with  `$(".UserLink").attr("href", "http://www.google.com");`